# How can I make a single query to retrieve data from two differences of Cloud Firestore collection?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

Dear Swift and Cloud firestore developers, 
I'm developing Chat app using swift and cloud firestore database. This is my collections:

```
Messages:
    + senderId
    + serceiverId
    + text
    + date
Users
    + userId
    + name
    + email
    + profilePic
    + phoneNumber
    + date
```

Let's say I'm logging in, my problem is that I want list all users (`profilePic` & `name`) who had chats history with me.
But is there any way I can use only single query of Firestore to retrieve the list of users?

Here is my current codes:

```
            var usersList : [User]! 

            private lazy var usersRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users") 

            private lazy var messagesRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Messages")

            var uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid as! String 

            messagesRef.whereField("senderId", isEqualTo: uid).order(by: "date_modified", 
            descending:true).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in 

                if let error = error { 

                    print("Error getting documents: \(error)")

                } else { 

                    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else { 

                        print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)") 
                        return 
                    } 

                    snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in 
                        if (diff.type == .added) { 
                            let da = diff.document.data() as! NSDictionary 

                            let receiverId = da["receiverId"] as! String 
                            self.usersRef.whereField("userId", isEqualTo:  
             receiverId).getDocuments(completion: { (udata, error) in 

                                for document in udata!.documents { 
                                    let du:[String:Any] = document.data() 

                                    let name = du["name"] as! String 
                                    let email = du["email"] as! String 
                                    self.usersList.append(User(userId: receiverId, name: 
             name, email:email)) 
                                    self.tableView.reloadData() 

                                } 

                            }) 

                        } 

                      } 

                   } 

                } 

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get data from two collections with a single read. You will either have to:

1. duplicate the necessary data from each user into each of their messages (known as denormalization), or
2. perform additional reads to get the user data, known as client-side joins.

Both of these are *very* normal on a NoSQL database. If you're new to the concept, I recommend:

- reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s). While this was created for the Firebase Realtime Database, the main concepts apply equally to Cloud Firestore.
- watching the brand new [What is a NoSQL Database? How is Cloud Firestore structured?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ) video.